# Align nested element to top of div using nth-child property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to assign `.dropdown .has-panel ul .dd-panel:nth-child(2)` different `top:x` values but it seems my nth-child is not working correct as i may be doing something wrong.

fiddle sample http://jsfiddle.net/Ed9nk/4/

I need to align `Level 3/ Grand Child` menus at top of the container like `level 2 /Child` menus so that respective level3 me menus always show at top.

[image]

i added following css

```
/* has set top: -64px; manually so that Parent One > Child Menu> Grand Child align to top*/    
.dropdown ul ul .dd-panel {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 red;
        border-left: 0px solid #30a784;
        border-right: 0px solid #008438;
        bottom: 0;
        display: none;
        font-size: 11px;
        height: 100%;
        left: 175px;
        line-height: 15px;
        min-height: 100px;
        padding: 10px;
        position: absolute;
        text-align: justify;
        top: -64px;
        width: 400px;

    }
    .dropdown .has-panel ul .dd-panel:nth-child(2)
    {
    top: -64px;
    background-color:green;
    }
    .dropdown .has-panel ul .dd-panel:nth-child(4)
    {
    top: -164px;
    background-color:yellow !important;
    }
```

My simple question is i always want Image & Text related to level 2 or level 3 menus to show up as top, i tried so many thing but nothing is working finally if thought of working with nth-child but i am not abel to get it right may be mixed up elements.

Comment: This html is too complicated. I suggest making two divs inside of your container - sub_nav and content. tie them together with data attributes so that in your javascript you can determine which content to show based on which sub_nav li has been hovered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your Image you have added in your question, I am going to give the solution. Update your CSS like below.

```
 ul.nav > li > .dropdown.has-panel li:nth-child(3) > .dropdown.has-panel .dd-panel
{
  margin-top: -90px;
  background-color:green !important;
 }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ed9nk/7/)